# Load extra category to a category product list page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

I'm trying to achieve a custom layout that displays two categories on a specific page.

For example, I have a New Arrivals page that lists the products for this category with a category ID of 5. On this page, I want to also show 12 products that are in their own category of Top Picks with a category id of 15.

So far, I've successfully created a new layout and updated the category page to use this layout for a custom design.

**NOTE: We use ManaDev's AJAX product and filter plugins to do sorting, etc. This feature would have to work for both categories that are being loaded onto the page.**

I've created a module called Newarrivals which contains a Lists.php block and config.xml file.

The Lists.php block extends the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List.

I've tried manually setting the category ID's in the _getProductCollection function and push each array of products into another associative array and display them in the layout.

In my layout.xml file I've done something like this:

```
<new_arrivals_layout>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <script>css/responsive-catalog.css</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="tm_newarrivals/lists" name="lists" template="tm/newarrivals/lists.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</new_arrivals_layout>
```

I guess my first issue is that the lists.phtml block is not rendering. But I was getting an error at one point where it was saying I can't set the current page value on a null value, or something similar to those lines.

Here's the config.xml for my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <TM_Newarrivals>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </TM_Newarrivals>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <tm_newarrivals>
        <class>TM_Newarrivals_Block</class>
      </tm_newarrivals>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Here's a shortened version of Newarrivals/Block/Lists.php

```
class TM_Newarrivals_Block_Lists extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
  /**
   * Retrieve loaded category collection
   * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
   */
  protected function _getProductCollection()
  {
    $categories = [5, 15];
    foreach ($categories as $id) {
      // Code to get products and push into array.
    }
    // Other code
    return $this->_productCollection;
  }
```

Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated.